# Gmail API - Parse message content (Base64 decoding?) with Javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, base64, gmail-api

I'm trying to use the Gmail API to get a user's email, grab the message subject and body, and then display it on a webpage. I'll be doing other stuff with it, but this is the part that I am having difficulty with. I am using Angular.js.

Here is my API call:

```
function makeApiCall() {
  gapi.client.load('gmail', 'v1', function() {
    var request = gapi.client.gmail.users.messages.list({
      labelIds: ['INBOX']
    });
    request.execute(function(resp) {
      var content = document.getElementById("message-list");
      angular.forEach(resp, function(message) {
        var email = gapi.client.gmail.users.messages.get({'id': message.id});
        // var raw = email.payload.parts;
        // console.log(raw);
        content.innerHTML += JSON.stringify(email) + "<br>";
      })
    });
  });
}
```

So `gapi.client.gmail.users.messages.list` returns an array of my messages, with their ID numbers. That is working.

The call to `gapi.client.gmail.users.messages.get({<specific message ID>})` outputs this - `{"B":{"method":"gmail.users.messages.get","rpcParams":{},"transport":{"name":"googleapis"}}}`.

Not sure what that is, but trying to get the message payload (`email.payload.parts`), results in `undefined`. So, how can I get the message content?

Also, I would assume that if I can get the message contents, I would then have to Base64 decode the contents to get some English out of it. Any suggestions for that would be of great help also. I've found this: https://github.com/kvz/phpjs, but since I'm not sure how to go about getting the message contents so that I can try and decode them, so not sure if that php.js is of an help in that regard.

Comment: For those who are looking for an npm package, try this https://www.npmjs.com/package/gmail-api-parse-message

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depending on what your emails look like (single text/plain part?  multipart with text/html?  attachments, etc?) you may or may not have any "parts" in your email.payload and instead you'll have what you're looking for in "email.payload.body.data" (for single-part messages).  This is all assuming you're doing a message.get with the default format ("full").  If you instead want to get the entire email in the message.raw field and deal with it in email libraries for your language you can call message.get(format=raw).

For more info check out the "body" and "parts[]" field documentation for "Message" at https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages

Comment: When trying to log `gapi.client.gmail.users.messages.get({<message id>}).payload.body.data`, it outputs `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'body' of undefined`. However when testing out the .get method call on the Gmail API documentation (I knew about that link you posted) at the Try it! section of the messages.get part, I can see content in the payload field of my message object, so it shouldn't be undefined.

Although for parts[], it says `For...text/plain, this field is empty.` A basic email message would contain plain text, correct? So maybe that's not where I'm supposed to go..

Answer (score 43):

Regarding the Base64 decoding, you can use

```
atob(dataToDecode)
```

For Gmail, you'll also want to replace some characters:

```
atob( dataToDecode.replace(/-/g, '+').replace(/_/g, '/') );
```

The above function is available to you in JavaScript (see [ref](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_atob.asp)). I use it myself to decode the Gmail messages. No need to install extra stuff. As an interesting tangent, if you want to encode your message to Base64, use btoa.

Now, for accessing your message payload, you can write a function:

```
var extractField = function(json, fieldName) {
  return json.payload.headers.filter(function(header) {
    return header.name === fieldName;
  })[0].value;
};
var date = extractField(response, "Date");
var subject = extractField(response, "Subject");
```

referenced from my previous [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28599753/how-to-parse-json-from-gmail-api-using-javascript) and

```
var part = message.parts.filter(function(part) {
  return part.mimeType == 'text/html';
});
var html = atob(part.body.data.replace(/-/g, '+').replace(/_/g, '/'));
```

Comment: Oh my _gOoOd_ thank you for that GMail tip. I was trying to figure out why my decoding was coming out garbled on `raw` messages.

Comment: ooooh my, your gmail replace tip just saved me

Comment: Thankss!!!

It worked but in the parsing having some problems but some characters.

for eg: `Â` characters in between random strings and etc.

Answer (score 3):

Ah! I figured it out. `parts` is an array, so I should have been calling it like: `gapi.client.gmail.users.messages.get({'id': <message ID>}).payload.parts[0].body.data`

Now my problem is decoding the emails, which is proving successful in plain text emails, but failing in emails from non-personal locations (businesses, social media update emails, etc.). But I'll make a new question to get answers for that.

Comment: You should use a [library](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Base64_encoding_and_decoding) for encoding and decoding

Comment: See my answer above for encoding/decoding

Answer (score 0):

You need to search where the body for a given mime type is, I have written a recursive function for that:

```
function searchBodyRec(payload, mimeType){
    if (payload.body && payload.body.size && payload.mimeType === mimeType) {
        return payload.body.data;
    } else if (payload.parts && payload.parts.length) {
        return payload.parts.flatMap(function(part){
            return searchBodyRec(part, mimeType);
        }).filter(function(body){
            return body;
        });
    }
}
```

So now you can call

```
var encodedBody = searchBodyRec(this.message.payload, 'text/plain');
```

See the flatMap method up there? Classic FP method missing in js, here is how to add it (or you can use lodash.js, or underscore.js if you don't want to mess with the native objects)

```
Array.prototype.flatMap = function(lambda) { 
    return Array.prototype.concat.apply([], this.map(lambda)); 
};
```