# Template to display Gmail API JSON output in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, json, templates, gmail-api

I can make calls to Gmail API and retrieve list of messages/thread in JSON.

I want to display these threads/messages to my users in HTML similar to a webmail like gmail itself.

Is there a html+css+js library or template out there that is designed to work with gmail API JSON outputs to display the messages nicely?

Answer (score 1):

You may check on this [related thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24428246/retrieve-email-message-body-in-html-using-gmail-api). It is stated that Email messages that have both HTML and plain text content will have multiple payload parts, and the part with the mimeType "text/html" will contains the HTML content. You can find it with logic like:

> ```
> var part = message.parts.filter(function(part) {
>   return part.mimeType == 'text/html';
> });
> var html = urlSafeBase64Decode(part.body.data);
> ```

You can also check on this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28599753/how-to-parse-json-from-gmail-api-using-javascript) how to parse JSON from Gmail API using JavaScript. Use [`filter`](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/settings/filters) function as follows:

> ```
> var extractField = function(json, fieldName) {
>   return json.payload.headers.filter(function(header) {
>     return header.name === fieldName;
>   })[0];
> };
> var date = extractField(response, "Date");
> var subject = extractField(response, "Subject");
> ```

Comment: Thank you and those are helpful. However, my question is if there is a library out there that I can through the json respond of list of messages at it and it spits out a html file nicely formatted. I just don't want to reinvent the wheel :)