# Get attachments in GMail API

Tags: go, gmail, gmail-api

I am trying to get an attachment from a mail in golang. The problem is in the base64 payload read from Gmail giving me the error

```
illegal base64 data at input byte 13
```

Here's my code (err handling omitted)
..

```
attach, _ := srv.Users.Messages.Attachments.Get(user, messageid, attachmentid).Do()
decoded, err := base64.StdEncoding.DecodeString(attach.Data)
```

This throws the mentioned error and if I look at the original message in GMail  can see after the headers this:

```
begin 644 filename-of-the-attachment.extension
M'XL(`/Y;GU8``^S]R[(>R9&E"\[[*5)JVI*6;N9WS(_TD3/J0<U:>H`*;F9"...
```

Any help appreciated 
Thanks

Comment: Which go package are you using to connect connect to Gmail?

Comment: "google.golang.org/api/gmail/v1"

Comment: you probably want to set the get parameter `format` to `raw` so you get base64: https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/get it looks like there's a method you need to use before call Do. https://github.com/google/google-api-go-client/blob/master/gmail/v1/gmail-gen.go#L3393

Comment: Seeing this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24745006/gmail-api-parse-message-content-base64-decoding-with-javascript and trying your idea, then let you know

Comment: Same goes with raw input...the base64 decode fails

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is in the base64 encoding: as the documentation say the payload (either in "full" or "raw" mode) is in base64URL encoding, not base64.
So this code is working:

```
attach, _ := srv.Users.Messages.Attachments.Get(user, messageid, attachmentid).Do()
decoded, err := base64.URLEncoding.DecodeString(attach.Data)
fileout, err := os.OpenFile(...
```

That said, I saw the full mode (default) is easier to handle
:)