# How do i get the body of an email from gmails api using node?

Tags: node.js, gmail, gmail-api

I am using Node.js, Gmail and Gmails API.

I am trying to read messages using gmails API.

To do this I:

```
async function getMessages(auth){
  const gmail = google.gmail({version: 'v1', auth});

  let theMessages =  await gmail.users.messages.list({
    userId:"me",
    maxResults:10
  })

  let theIds = theMessages.data.messages
  let theId = theIds[0].id

  let response = await gmail.users.messages.get({
    userId:"me",
    id:theId
  })

  let theData = response.data
}
```

However the response i get is an obeject with this information:

```
historyId:"1"
id:"1"
internalDate:"1"
labelIds:Array(4) ["UNREAD", "IMPORTANT", "SENT", …]
payload:Object {partId: "", mimeType: "multipart/alternative", filename: "", …}
body:Object {size: 0}
__proto__:Object {constructor: , __defineGetter__: , __defineSetter__: , …}
sizeEstimate:578
snippet:"Hey"
threadId:"1"
__proto__:Object {constructor: , __defineGetter__: , __defineSetter__: , …}
filename:""
headers:Array(7) [Object, Object, Object, …]
mimeType:"multipart/alternative"
partId:""
parts:Array(2) [Object, Object]
```

How do i get the body of an email from this information. I've tried looking at the body attribute, but only find a `size:0`. Part of the message is there as a `snippet`, but obviously the full message isn't.

any help is appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Gmail API - Parse message content (Base64 decoding?) with Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24745006/gmail-api-parse-message-content-base64-decoding-with-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

The message body is available inside `response.data.payload`, as defined in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.messages):

> payload: The parsed email structure in the message parts.

[MessagePart](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.messages#Message.MessagePart) section provides further details about the data structure, it is necessary to decode the base-64 encoded contents.

Comment: if you can tell me exactly what i need to decode.
e.g. 
payload.parts then where????